# edit httpd.conf to run PHP5?

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, php5, httpd.conf

I've installed apache and the server runs fine. I then installed PHP5, and it gave me a warning that it failed to edit the needed apache files.

I did some googling and I found an article that said I just needed to add this to any spot on the httpd.conf file.

```
LoadModule php5_module "J:/php/php5apache2_2.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "J:/php"
```

However when I do that and attempt to restart the service, apache fails to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue:

The distro of PHP5 (windows 32 installer .msi package from php.net) that I got, for some reason or another, was lacking all the .DLL files I needed. I downloaded the .zip and did a manual install.

BTW, for those like me who are looking to get started using a WAMP, I highly recomend doing it manualy. I've done it both ways now, and you learn a ton more doing the manual process.

Answer (score 1):

Open Apache log file to see why it can not start.